# ffmpeg dynamic image overlay

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, images

I would like to add an image overlay (That I can then update) To my Livestream that takes RTSP as input and streams it to youtube.

Here is the command.

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -y -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://myrtspurl -re -framerate 1 -loop 1 -f image2pipe -i pathtofile.png -filter_complex "[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a];[1:v][a]overlay=25:25" -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://youtubeurl`

Everything works great but no matter how I update the image it doesn't get updated on the Livestream.

To update the image I create a new image with a different name and then use Linux **mv** command
`mv newfile.png to oldfile.png`

I also tried saving/rewriting the image used by FFmpeg directly but still, the image stays the same.

Even if I remove the image used by FFmpeg completely nothing happens stream continues and I can still see the overlay that I added.

Thanks